# Saving only data sets that are not empty

Tags: validation, save, spss, is-empty

I have a large dataset where I do data validation using a syntax. For each validation a variable is created and set to 1 if there is a problem with data I need to check out.
For each validation I then create a subset of the data holding only the relevant variables for the relevant cases. Still using the syntax I save these data files in excel in order to do the checks and correct the data (in a database).

Problem is that not all of my 50+ validations detect any problematic data every time I run the check, but 50+ files are saved because I save a file for each validation. I'd like to save the files only if there is data in them.

Current syntax for saving the files is:

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
DATASET COPY  error1.
DATASET ACTIVATE  error1.
FILTER OFF.
USE ALL.
SELECT IF (var_error1 = 1).
EXECUTE.

SAVE TRANSLATE OUTFILE='path + '_error1.xlsx'
  /TYPE=XLS
  /VERSION=12
  /MAP
  /REPLACE
  /FIELDNAMES
  /CELLS=VALUES
  /KEEP=var1 var2 var3 var4.
```

This is repeated for each validation. If no case violates the validation for "error1" I will still get an output file (which is empty).

Any way to alter the syntax to only save the data if there are in fact cases that violate the validation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - Nice first question!

Answer (score 1):

The following syntax will write a new syntax that will contain the command to save the file to excel - only if there are actual cases in the file. You will run the new syntax every time, but the excel will be created only in relevant cases :

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
DATASET COPY  error1.
DATASET ACTIVATE  error1.
FILTER OFF.
USE ALL.
SELECT IF (var_error1 = 1).
EXECUTE.

do if $casenum=1.
  write outfile='path\tmp\run error1.sps' /"SAVE TRANSLATE OUTFILE='path\var_error1.xlsx'"
     /"  /TYPE=XLS  /VERSION=12  /MAP  /REPLACE  /FIELDNAMES  /CELLS=VALUES  /KEEP=var1 var2 var3 var4.".
end if.
exe.

insert file='path\tmp\run error1.sps'.
```

Please edit the "path" according to your needs.
Note that the new syntax will be written in all cases, but when there is no data in the file, the syntax will be empty, and so the empty file won't be written to excel.